# What are i.i.d. random variables?

Tags: random-variable, intuition, iid

How would you go about explaining i.i.d (independent and identically distributed) to non-technical people?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It means "Independent and identically distributed".

A good example is a succession of throws of a fair coin: The coin has no memory, so all the throws are "independent".

And every throw is 50:50 (heads:tails), so the coin is and stays fair - the distribution from which every throw is drawn, so to speak, is and stays the same: "identically distributed".

A good starting point would be the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables).

::EDIT::

Follow this [link](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/iid-statistics/) to further explore the concept.

Comment: I wonder if the coin toss example would falsely give the impression that every event must be equiprobable...

Comment: So, is it not necessary that the IID random variables should be equi-probable? if they are not equiprobable then how can the "identically distributed" be explained? Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: @Nalini "equi-probable" is not a synonym for "identically distributed." If $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d., this means they are taken from the same distribution, not that all values in that distribution are equally likely (think the normal distribution). $x$ and $y$ would have the same expected value, though.

Comment: If two variables are independent and normal distributed but with different mean and variance, are they still i.i.d?

Comment: @spurra I don't think so.. they are just independent

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote?!?

Comment: Well, the explanation covered the identical and independent parts of a sample/entire population space of a distribution. However, I feel that those two qualities/adjectives mean well in a  - continuous distribution space but not in a discrete space. Hence can we assume that i.i.d  always implicitly means the distribution considered is a continuous one? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @KarriChandrasekhar: No, when you look at my example of a fair coin this is a discrete random variable.

Comment: @vonjd - yes, that explains, thanks. What could be an intuitive example in terms of a continuous distribution- from a non-technical point of view? Thanks again.

Answer (score 32):

Nontechnical explanation:

*Independence* is a very general notion. Two events are said to be independent if the occurrence of one does not give you any information as to whether the other event occurred or not.  In particular,
the probability that we ascribe to the second event is not affected
by the knowledge that the first event has occurred.

- **Example of independent events, possibly identically distributed**
  Consider tossing two different coins one after the other. Assuming that
  your thumb did not get unduly tired when it flipped the first coin,
  it is reasonable to assume that knowing that the first coin toss resulted in Heads in no way influences what you think the probability
  of Heads on the second toss is.  The two events 
  $$\{\text{first coin toss resulted in Heads}\}~~\text{and}~~\{\text{second coin toss resulted in Heads}\}$$
  are said to be *independent* events.

  - If we know, or obstinately insist, that the two coins have different
    probabilities of resulting in Heads, then the events are *not
    identically distributed.*
  - If we *know* or *assume*
    that the two coins have the *same* probability $p$ of coming
    up Heads, then the above events are also *identically distributed,*
    meaning that they both have the same probability $p$ of occurring.
    But notice that unless $p = \frac 12$, the probability of Heads
    does not equal the probability of Tails. As noted in one of the
    Comments, "identical distribution" is not the same as "equally
    probable."
- **Example of identically distributed nonindependent events**
  Consider an urn with two balls in it, one black and one white.
  We reach into it and draw out the two balls one after the other,
  choosing the first one at random (and this of course determines
  the color of the next ball). Thus, the two equally
  likely outcomes of the experiment
  are (White, Black) and (Black, White), and we see that the first
  ball is equally likely to be Black or White and so is the second
  ball also equally likely to be Black or White.  In other words,
  the events
  $$\{\text{first ball drawn is Black}\}~~\text{and}~~\{\text{second ball drawn is Black}\}$$
  certainly are identically distributed, but they are definitely
  **not** independent events. Indeed, if we know that the first
  event has occurred, we know for sure that the second *cannot*
  occur. Thus, while our initial evaluation of the probability
  of the second event is $\frac 12$, once we know that the first
  event has occurred, we had best revise our assessment of the
  probability of the second drawn will be black from $\frac 12$ to $0$.

Comment: "As noted in one of the Comments, "identical distribution" is not the same as "equally probable."" What's the difference? "equally probable" means heads is equally likely as tails? Whereas "identically distributed" means each event has the same likelihood of heads?

Comment: @TheRedPea Not quite. If we have a biased coin that turns up H with probability $p \ne \frac 12$, then the _events_ "First Toss is H" and the event "Second Toss is H" are independent as well as equally probable (they both have probability $p$). Furthermore the _tosses_ are _identically distributed:_ they both have the same probabilities ($p$ and $1-p$ for H and T respectively) in the various tosses.  But the events "First Toss is H" and "First Toss is T" are _not equally probable_. Nor are they independent.  _Identical distribution_ =  all tosses have same _distribution_.

Comment: @TheRedPea (continued) Equally probable means two _events_ have the same probability. The events  may be defined across tosses as above, or within a single experiment. The canonical simple model of an experiment is of a sample space with $n$ outcomes in which _all_  the outcomes have the same probability $\frac 1n$. It is common to describe this by saying "a fair coin" or "a fair dice" or saying things like "A ball is chosen at random from an urn with 3 green balls and 2 red balls" etc. It is only the purists who will cavil and insist that it should be "a fair die" ....

Comment: OK so identical distribution refers to the entire probability distribution, whereas equal probability refers to parts of that probability distribution. I understand now, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the last example being identically distributed. Is it arguable that "*if* two events are not independent, they can not be from identical distributions"? E.g. in your example I'd say the second ball-drawing has a different distribution due to the first event.

Comment: @jiggunjer No it is not correct to say that if two events are not independent then they cannot be from identical distributions of two reasons. First, **events** do not have distributions: they have probability.  _Random variables_ have distributions. Second, even if your statement is modified to make sense, it is nonetheless false. You can _make_ the argument along the lines that you have chosen, but don't be disappointed  when people refuse to accept your argument.

Comment: You're saying I'm not correct because I'm wrong. I'd hardly call that 2 reasons. In the example you sample from a distribution to get x1 and then you sample x2, which are values of the random variable X. I would say x2 is sampled from a different distribution, one where p(X=x1) is zero? Also I noticed you say "not independent" instead of "dependent", is that common or just for emphasis?

Comment: I just copied your words. That "not independent" is a synonym for "dependent" but when discussing independence or the _lack thereof_ I prefer to use "not independent" to describe lack thereof.  My example shows that the _events_ "first ball is black" and "second ball is black are indeed _dependent_ events, but they nonetheless have the same probability. If instead the balls are numbered $0$ and $1$, then the _random Variables_ $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _dependent:_ indeed $X_2 = 1-X_1$ but they both nonetheless enjoy the same Bernoulli$\left(\frac 12\right)$ distribution.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer! The accepted answer is incorrect about "identically distributed".

Comment: @DilipSarwate , This is really a great answer. It will be really helpful for me, if you please can answer [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457742/can-we-use-permutation-test-everywhere-to-check-difference-when-the-null-hypothe) also which is related to ex-changeability.

Answer (score 7):

A random variable is variable which contains the probability of all possible events in a scenario. For example, lets create a random variable which represents the number of heads in 100 coin tosses. The random variable will contain the probability of getting 1 heads, 2 heads, 3 heads.....all the way to 100 heads. Lets call this random variable ***X***.

If you have two random variables then they are **IID** (independent identically distributed) if:

1. If they are **independent**. As explained above independence means the occurrence of one event does not provide any information about the other event. For example, if I get 100 heads after 100 flips, the probabilities of getting heads or tails in the next flip are the same.
2. If each random variable shares the same **distribution**. For example, lets take the random variable from above - ***X***. Lets say **X** represents Obama about to flip a coin 100 times. Now let's say **Y** represents a Priest about to flip a coin 100 times. If Obama and the Priest flip coins with the same probability of landing on heads, then **X** and **Y** are considered identically distributed. If we sample repeatedly from either the Priest or Obama, then the samples are considered identically distributed.

Side note: Independence also means you can multiply probabilities. Lets say the probability of heads is p, then the probability of getting two heads in a row is p*p, or p^2.

Answer (score 2):

That two dependent variables can have the same distribution can be shown with this example:

Assume two successive experiments involving each 100 tosses of a biased coin, where the total number of Head is modeled as a random variable X1 for the first experiment and X2 for the second experiment.  X1 and X2 are binomial random variables with parameters 100 and p, where p the bias of the coin.
As such, they are identically distributed.  However they are not independent, since the value of the former is quite informative about the value of the latter.  That is if the result of the first experiment is 100 Heads this tells us a lot about the bias of the coin and therefore gives us a lot new information regarding the distribution of X2.
Still X2 and X1 are identically distributed since they are derived from the same coin.

What is also true is that if 2 random variables are dependent then the posterior of X2 given X1 will never be the same as the prior of X2 and vice versa.  While when X1 and X2 are independent their posteriors are equal to their priors.  Therefore, when two variables are dependent, the observation of one of them results in revised estimates regarding the distribution of the second.  Still both may be from the same distribution, it is just we learn in the process more about the nature of this distribution.  So returning to the coin tosses experiments, initially in the absence of any information we might assume that X1 and X2 follow a Binomial distribution with parameters 100 and 0.5.  But after observing 100 Heads on a row we would certainly revise our estimate about the p parameter to make it quite close to 1.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this. The experiments themselves should be independent. Observing one experiment won't change the outcome of the other experiment. The physics of the experiment doesn't change. So I wouldn't say that X1 and X2 are independent. Like you mention in the last paragraph, the estimates of parameter p are dependent, which we can treat as a random variable itself say P. So as you mention, P2 (r.v. for estimate of p for X2) is dependent on P1 given we observed X1, right?

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation of several random draws from the same distribution. An example being pulling a marble out of bag 10,000 times and counting the times you pull the red marble out.

Comment: Can you expand on how this adds to the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

If a random variable $X$ comes from a population having (say) a normal distribution, that is its pdf (probability density function) is that of normal distribution, with a population average $\mu=3$ and population variance $\sigma^2=4$ (the numbers are hypothetical and are just for your understanding and to simplify comparisons) we can describe it as follows: $X \sim N(3 , 4)$.

Now if we have another random variable $Y$ which is also normally distributed and which is $Y \sim N(3, 4)$ then $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Nevertheless, being identically distributed does not necessarily imply independence.

Comment: You must have an interesting set of "nontechnical people" in mind when you rely on technical terms like "random variable," "normal distribution," "pdf," "variance," and "independence."  I would venture to say it's the empty set.

Comment: "*being identically distributed does not necessarily imply independence*". How can dependence have an effect on two identically distributed variables? It would seem to me, that **dependence causes non-identicality, but not all non-identicality is due to dependence**.