# About ideal data and its distribution

Tags: distributions, dataset

I was just thinking about what would be the properties of an ideal data set $X \in R^{n,d}$ where n is sample size, d represents features. I think (or at least I understood from reading text books) that there are 2 things that has to be satisfied :

1. Each feature ($d_{i}$) must be independent from each other so that the feature space is Positive Definite, which in turn $X^{T}X$ also has condition number close/equal to 1.
2. There has to be enough samples ($n$) that prevents the data from curse of dimensionality

Is this enough?

After these requirements are satisfied, could we directly infer about the distribution of the data ? Is there any rule of thumb? For instance, if those 2 (or more) steps are satisfied than the data must be Gaussian or another distribution.

I am trying to fill the gap between statistical properties and the algebraic properties of the data. Hence, I am little confused of building the relationship between them. Could someone explain me where should I check about the materials for building this relationship? Or take time and explain me ?

Comment: "Ideal" in what sense? Being independent or the number of samples has nothing to do with distribution. Why does finding "ideal" data bothers you?

Comment: 1 . "Being independent or the number of samples has nothing to do with distribution." I was wondering if there is a relationship in between.   2. " Why does finding "ideal" data bothers you?" Because, I am/was thinking that when we apply preprocessing or post processing to any data, we actually transform it into a more proper form which results a different shape of that distirbution or may be a different kind of distribution. And in some cases, transforming the data and giving it to the model increases the overall performance, and in other cases it decreases.

Comment: So the transformation process on the input data effects the shape/distribution of the  data hence gives better performance. I accept that also the model used is important.

Comment: What kind of transformations?

Comment: From the experiments that I am doing, I observe that if we apply unit, center and unit normalizations I get 2 things  compared to original input : 1. Faster convergence, 2. higher accuracy. And these 2 operations (unit, centering) does affect the shape of the data and also condition number which makes me build relationship between stats and algebra.

Comment: And the model is least squares.

Comment: I'm lost. What is your question? Could you summarize it in one sentence? It sounds like you are asking "how to preprocess data for machine learning/statistical inference" but this would need a whole book rather than Q&A answer.

Comment: Is there any way to infer about the distribution of the data  by just checking its feature space ($X^{T}X$)? Of course by applying normalization steps so it is actually covariance matrix.

Comment: As far I as understand the question, it is really dependant of what you are doing .. for predicition with xgboost, for exemple, postive definite feature space is not particularly ideal .. (if I don't mislead myself ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the clarified question from the comment

> Is there any way to infer about the distribution of the data  by just checking its feature space ($X^{T}X$)?

No. Let's start from the very beginning, say that you have a dataset with $n$ rows (samples) and $k$ columns, in statistics you would think of this dataset as a [random matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix) or $n \times k$ random variables. The shape of the dataset tells you nothing of the distributions of the random variables because you assume that each of the $n \times k$ points is a realization of a separate random variable. To simplify things, in many cases, you would assume the samples (e.g. rows, treated as $n$ random vectors of size $k$) to be [independent and identically distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17391/what-are-i-i-d-random-variables) multivariate random varaibles, but this has nothing to do with the shape of the dataset. You can also have a random matrix consisting of $n \times k$ random variables following different distributions, that are non-independent.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. B.R.